# Как вызвать ConfigurationManager в C#

Tags: c#

Всем доброго времени суток, у меня такая проблема - есть консольное приложение в котором я хочу вызвать ConfigurationManager но в IntelliSense нет выбора данного класса.

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;

    class Program
        {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var context = new TestDataContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

     var roles = context.Roles.ToList();
            foreach (var role in roles)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", role.ID, role.Code, role.Name);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться что я не так делаю ? Спасибо

Comment: Что в вашем понимании есть "mvc приложение"? Сообщите версию платформы и тип проекта.

Comment: @PavelMayorov MVC : "модель-представление-контроллер" - тоесть модель приложения, пользовательский интерфейс и взаимодействие с пользователем разделены на три отдельных компонента. Используется в web программировании. Вы это хотели услышать ?

Comment: Не вполне понятно, откуда у вас в web-приложении метод Main и работа с консолью

Comment: @PavelMayorov "Теперь я создаю тестовое консольное приложение, и делаю подключение в References к mvc с LINQ to SQL Classes"

Comment: А, ясно. Но вы разве не видите, что ни mvc, ни LINQ to SQL Classes, ни консольность приложения не имеют ни малейшего отношения к вашей проблеме?

Comment: @PavelMayorov Да вижу, сейчас поправлю тему, просто не понимаю почему я не могу обратиться к `ConfigurationManager` в чем может быть проблема ?

Comment: Прочитайте мой первый комментарий. Вы сообщили не всю информацию.

Comment: _В итоге получаю ошибку о том что нет такого имени ConfigurationManager._ - Добавь полный текст ошибки

Comment: @Grundy Исправил суть вопроса, просто в  IntelliSense нет такого класса хотя сборки добавлены

Comment: @PavelMayorov VS 2015, .NET Framework 4.5.2, Console Application

Comment: _в IntelliSense нет выбора данного класса._ - но само приложение собирается и не падает? или как?

Comment: @Grundy `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0103 The name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the current context Lesson1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам надо добавить в проект ссылку на сборку `System.Configuration`. Класс `ConfigurationManager` находится в ней. По умолчанию она в проект не добавлена. Кликните в проекте правой кнопкой по Reference, выберите пункт AddReference, в открывшемся окне появится список сборок. Там найдите `System.Configuration` и отметьте её. Должно работать.

Comment: `using System.Configuration;` не подходит ?

Comment: Директива `using` всего лишь говорит о необходимости использовать пространство имён (по идее можно и вовсе обойтись без неё, указывая полные имена классов, но это неудобно). Вам же надо добавить в проект саму сборку, в которой находится это пространство  имён и нужный вам класс.

Comment: О боже. Первая мысль была такая же, но я прочитал что автор добавил сборку. Мысль что "добавлением сборки" он назвал `using` - даже в голову не пришла...

Comment: @DreamChild Спасибо